# confusion over a recursive selection sort function

Tags: c, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive selection sort function where it picks the biggest number and puts it at the back. I used printf to see where it goes wrong, and it stops on the 8th iteration just before the for loop, when I input "1 8 15 3 17 12 4 8 4". I'm getting a segmentation error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void swap(int* ptr1, int* ptr2);
int selection_sort2(int A[], int n, int itr);

int 
main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int temp_array[1000], counter=0, i, itr=0;
    
    printf("Enter as many as 1000 values, ^D to end\n");
    while(scanf("%d", &temp_array[counter]) == 1){
        counter++;
        }
        
    printf("%d values read into array\n", counter);
    printf("Before: ");
    for(i=0; i<counter;i++){
        printf("%4d", temp_array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    selection_sort2(temp_array, counter, itr);

    return 0;
    }
void swap(int* ptr1, int* ptr2){
    int temp;   
    temp = *ptr1;
    *ptr1 = *ptr2;
    *ptr2 = temp;
}

int selection_sort2(int A[], int n, int itr){
    int j,temp, max, i;
    int itrs = itr;
    printf("%d\n", n);
    if(n==1){    
        printf("After2: ");
        for(i=0; i<n+itrs;i++){
            printf("%4d", A[i]);
        }
        return 1;
    }

    temp = A[n-1];
    for(j=n-1;j>=0;j--){
        printf("ok");
        printf("what %d ", j);
        if(A[j]>temp){
            max = j;
            temp = A[j];
        }
    }

    if(max!= n-1){ 
        swap(&A[n-1], &A[max]);
        }

    itrs++;
    return selection_sort2(A,n-1,itrs);
}
```

Comment: *I'm getting a segmentation error*. On which exact line of code? Running the code in a debugger will give you that info instantly. And the debugger can also be used to step thru the code and examine the state as it runs.

Comment: `if(max!= n-1) swap(&A[n-1], &A[max]);` That's one problem. `max` is not initialised and not all code paths set it. So that will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @kaylum it occurs on line 39, in the swap function.

Comment: keep using the debugger. Examine the values of `n` and `max` when the crash occurs. And so on. It's much better to learn to debug effectively yourself rather than rely on others to do it for you.

Comment: A couple of off-topic observations. 1) If you print the array in `main` after sorting, you can eliminate `itr` and `itrs` from the function. 2) There's no reason for the function to return a value. The only thing it will ever return is `1`, and `main` ignores the return value. So it would be better to declare the function as `void selection_sort2(int A[], int n)`

Comment: @user3386109 those points are true, thank you

Comment: @kaylum thanks ill learn how to use a debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is that uninitialized variable `max` and not determining when to stop the sorting/swap

when your array is already sorted and your iterator is greater than 1 (in this case by the time `n` value becomes 2, the array is already sorted), your `if(A[j]>temp){` will not be satisfied, hence `max` will have a junk value and with that junk value below statements will be called and is causing crash.

```
if(max!= n-1){ 
    swap(&A[n-1], &A[max]);
}
```

**Solution to handle the crash**

take a variable `int swapped = 0` at the beginning of the program, and make `swapped = 1` when condition `if(A[j]>temp){` satisfies.

Remember you will have to change your `swap`condition to `if(swapped && max != n-1){`

to conclude you will have to do following changes

```
int j,temp, max, i, swapped = 0;
static int count = 0;

if(A[j]>temp)
{
    max = j;
    temp = A[j];
    swapped = 1
}
// this will let you know the cause of the crash
printf("\n after %d iteration max = %d and temp =%d\n",++count,max,temp );

if(swapped && max != n-1)
{
    swap(&A[n-1], &A[max]);
}
```